# How do I create this simple layout?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a layout like this:
[image: simple layout]

My problem is that I'm not so well acquainted with "position" css tag. So at first I was positioning left and right sidebar like this:

```
overflow: hidden;
position:fixed;
top: 90px;
width: 260px !important;
bottom: 0;
left: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
padding-bottom: 50px;
```

Only difference between them is that instead of left I use right for the other one. I dont want to specify a number of pixels for height. But when I use Height 100% for main content It doesn't overwrap and also its height gets bigger than the navbars.

Well, cutting things short, my question is: **How do I create this fullscreen layout?** I made gutters in the drawing just to show that are 3 columns. My page doesn`t have gutters.

Comment: Do you want it fixed or responsive?

Comment: Responsive. Main users will be using tablet so I can't let it static.

Comment: Okay, so then what do you want it to look like when it shrinks? How do you want the different pieces to move? Or do you just want it to squish horizontally and never wrap?

Comment: I've created a javascript that push sidebars out of sight with a css transition. My MAIN problem is getting my main wrapper (the one in the center) to be 100% height and overwrap. If i set it 100% it will grow bigger than the sidebars and also its content will not overwrap.

Comment: What do you mean by "overwrap"? That is not a web design term

Comment: HAHAHAHA SORRY!!! overflow!! I meant overflow. I'm awake for 24 hours.

Comment: Make life easy, start using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created whatever is in the image, please note the content is not responsive, if responsive is needed please go for bootstrap.

***Note: Please view the answer in full screen mode!***

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div:not(.wrapper) {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.topbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 1%;
  left: 1%;
  height: 200px;
}

.left-nav {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1%;
  width: 18%;
}

.right-nav {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1%;
  width: 18%;
}

.main {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1%;
  width: 78%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 220px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
  topbar
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-nav">
    left nav
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tincidunt id tellus ut scelerisque. Nullam dapibus id orci ac congue. Nunc mattis dictum dui id euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam lorem turpis,
    venenatis nec rutrum et, blandit ac risus. Integer non sem quam. Mauris dictum, nisl id sollicitudin eleifend, purus ligula hendrerit mi, vitae ornare neque arcu pellentesque quam. Suspendisse consequat interdum dolor, maximus elementum metus lobortis
    vitae. Phasellus interdum erat vitae imperdiet pharetra. Sed vestibulum tellus arcu, vel hendrerit nisl elementum ut. Quisque non finibus dolor, non convallis libero. Pellentesque feugiat metus nisl, vel laoreet ligula posuere eu. In in tincidunt
    mi. In pharetra fermentum risus, non elementum erat blandit vel. Sed at turpis sed turpis finibus auctor. Morbi condimentum congue eros, nec sodales ligula fringilla vel. Suspendisse a nibh at massa convallis suscipit. Vestibulum accumsan lacus a
    facilisis molestie. Ut efficitur sodales ipsum eget pulvinar. Suspendisse faucibus rhoncus odio, convallis lacinia metus fringilla ac. Donec tincidunt tellus quis diam pharetra pellentesque. Praesent a mollis diam, eu vestibulum libero. Quisque euismod
    bibendum nibh in tempor. Curabitur congue ut tellus a malesuada. Proin id vestibulum velit. Pellentesque quis elit quis nulla lobortis bibendum in vitae odio. Maecenas eu rhoncus lectus. Quisque aliquet metus id facilisis egestas. Nunc posuere, felis
    in commodo viverra, eros ipsum pulvinar neque, sit amet accumsan massa tellus varius magna. Quisque id risus pharetra, pulvinar ipsum ut, sodales sapien. Curabitur euismod odio quis lectus hendrerit fringilla. Sed lorem libero, euismod quis accumsan
    ac, aliquam in ligula. Integer imperdiet enim non sapien luctus, a iaculis lorem tempus. Morbi ut pulvinar quam. Vivamus sodales justo ac metus laoreet, a condimentum turpis ultricies. Fusce enim risus, volutpat nec tempus vel, efficitur eget eros.
    Integer ac augue ut arcu pulvinar rhoncus. Vivamus tellus dui, posuere eu gravida sed, tempor eget sem. Praesent efficitur diam eget neque rhoncus auctor. Praesent tincidunt mauris sit amet lectus cursus gravida. Cras condimentum vestibulum euismod.
    Donec sit amet tellus at enim volutpat egestas. Maecenas risus tellus, aliquam vel sodales at, sagittis id lacus. Fusce pellentesque erat nunc. Suspendisse id cursus mauris. Donec ac pellentesque nibh. Ut vulputate lacus nec justo maximus mollis a
    nec nisl. Aliquam lectus diam, interdum vitae tellus quis, lacinia varius elit. Nam vehicula feugiat condimentum. Pellentesque at magna aliquet, vehicula sapien non, tincidunt nisi. Fusce convallis, orci dignissim faucibus placerat, massa lacus bibendum
    orci, suscipit mattis enim nunc lacinia est. Cras ante sem, dictum at metus eu, sagittis cursus mi. Integer in purus convallis, consectetur eros et, pulvinar risus. Fusce molestie nibh et purus pulvinar, non volutpat quam efficitur. Nulla facilisis
    metus non ornare elementum. Donec mollis tempor neque, sit amet varius nibh egestas sed. Integer vel dolor fermentum, dignissim urna ac, condimentum lacus. Proin imperdiet venenatis orci, et placerat magna dignissim in. Aliquam lobortis scelerisque
    maximus. Pellentesque sit amet libero in leo volutpat dignissim at vitae ligula. Nullam et sem nunc.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tincidunt id tellus ut scelerisque. Nullam dapibus id orci ac congue. Nunc mattis
    dictum dui id euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam lorem turpis, venenatis nec rutrum et, blandit ac risus. Integer non sem quam. Mauris dictum, nisl id sollicitudin eleifend, purus ligula hendrerit mi, vitae
    ornare neque arcu pellentesque quam. Suspendisse consequat interdum dolor, maximus elementum metus lobortis vitae. Phasellus interdum erat vitae imperdiet pharetra. Sed vestibulum tellus arcu, vel hendrerit nisl elementum ut. Quisque non finibus dolor,
    non convallis libero. Pellentesque feugiat metus nisl, vel laoreet ligula posuere eu. In in tincidunt mi. In pharetra fermentum risus, non elementum erat blandit vel. Sed at turpis sed turpis finibus auctor. Morbi condimentum congue eros, nec sodales
    ligula fringilla vel. Suspendisse a nibh at massa convallis suscipit. Vestibulum accumsan lacus a facilisis molestie. Ut efficitur sodales ipsum eget pulvinar. Suspendisse faucibus rhoncus odio, convallis lacinia metus fringilla ac. Donec tincidunt
    tellus quis diam pharetra pellentesque. Praesent a mollis diam, eu vestibulum libero. Quisque euismod bibendum nibh in tempor. Curabitur congue ut tellus a malesuada. Proin id vestibulum velit. Pellentesque quis elit quis nulla lobortis bibendum in
    vitae odio. Maecenas eu rhoncus lectus. Quisque aliquet metus id facilisis egestas. Nunc posuere, felis in commodo viverra, eros ipsum pulvinar neque, sit amet accumsan massa tellus varius magna. Quisque id risus pharetra, pulvinar ipsum ut, sodales
    sapien. Curabitur euismod odio quis lectus hendrerit fringilla. Sed lorem libero, euismod quis accumsan ac, aliquam in ligula. Integer imperdiet enim non sapien luctus, a iaculis lorem tempus. Morbi ut pulvinar quam. Vivamus sodales justo ac metus
    laoreet, a condimentum turpis ultricies. Fusce enim risus, volutpat nec tempus vel, efficitur eget eros. Integer ac augue ut arcu pulvinar rhoncus. Vivamus tellus dui, posuere eu gravida sed, tempor eget sem. Praesent efficitur diam eget neque rhoncus
    auctor. Praesent tincidunt mauris sit amet lectus cursus gravida. Cras condimentum vestibulum euismod. Donec sit amet tellus at enim volutpat egestas. Maecenas risus tellus, aliquam vel sodales at, sagittis id lacus. Fusce pellentesque erat nunc.
    Suspendisse id cursus mauris. Donec ac pellentesque nibh. Ut vulputate lacus nec justo maximus mollis a nec nisl. Aliquam lectus diam, interdum vitae tellus quis, lacinia varius elit. Nam vehicula feugiat condimentum. Pellentesque at magna aliquet,
    vehicula sapien non, tincidunt nisi. Fusce convallis, orci dignissim faucibus placerat, massa lacus bibendum orci, suscipit mattis enim nunc lacinia est. Cras ante sem, dictum at metus eu, sagittis cursus mi. Integer in purus convallis, consectetur
    eros et, pulvinar risus. Fusce molestie nibh et purus pulvinar, non volutpat quam efficitur. Nulla facilisis metus non ornare elementum. Donec mollis tempor neque, sit amet varius nibh egestas sed. Integer vel dolor fermentum, dignissim urna ac, condimentum
    lacus. Proin imperdiet venenatis orci, et placerat magna dignissim in. Aliquam lobortis scelerisque maximus. Pellentesque sit amet libero in leo volutpat dignissim at vitae ligula. Nullam et sem nunc. Pellentesque at magna aliquet, vehicula sapien
    non, tincidunt nisi. Fusce convallis, orci dignissim faucibus placerat, massa lacus bibendum orci, suscipit mattis enim nunc lacinia est. Cras ante sem, dictum at metus eu, sagittis cursus mi. Integer in purus convallis, consectetur eros et, pulvinar
    risus. Fusce molestie nibh et purus pulvinar, non volutpat quam efficitur. Nulla facilisis metus non ornare elementum. Donec mollis tempor neque, sit amet varius nibh egestas sed. Integer vel dolor fermentum, dignissim urna ac, condimentum lacus.
    Proin imperdiet venenatis orci, et placerat magna dignissim in. Aliquam lobortis scelerisque maximus. Pellentesque sit amet libero in leo volutpat dignissim at vitae ligula. Nullam et sem nunc.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Aliquam tincidunt id tellus ut scelerisque. Nullam dapibus id orci ac congue. Nunc mattis dictum dui id euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam lorem turpis, venenatis nec rutrum et, blandit ac risus. Integer
    non sem quam. Mauris dictum, nisl id sollicitudin eleifend, purus ligula hendrerit mi, vitae ornare neque arcu pellentesque quam. Suspendisse consequat interdum dolor, maximus elementum metus lobortis vitae. Phasellus interdum erat vitae imperdiet
    pharetra. Sed vestibulum tellus arcu, vel hendrerit nisl elementum ut. Quisque non finibus dolor, non convallis libero. Pellentesque feugiat metus nisl, vel laoreet ligula posuere eu. In in tincidunt mi. In pharetra fermentum risus, non elementum
    erat blandit vel. Sed at turpis sed turpis finibus auctor. Morbi condimentum congue eros, nec sodales ligula fringilla vel. Suspendisse a nibh at massa convallis suscipit. Vestibulum accumsan lacus a facilisis molestie. Ut efficitur sodales ipsum
    eget pulvinar. Suspendisse faucibus rhoncus odio, convallis lacinia metus fringilla ac. Donec tincidunt tellus quis diam pharetra pellentesque. Praesent a mollis diam, eu vestibulum libero. Quisque euismod bibendum nibh in tempor. Curabitur congue
    ut tellus a malesuada. Proin id vestibulum velit. Pellentesque quis elit quis nulla lobortis bibendum in vitae odio. Maecenas eu rhoncus lectus. Quisque aliquet metus id facilisis egestas. Nunc posuere, felis in commodo viverra, eros ipsum pulvinar
    neque, sit amet accumsan massa tellus varius magna. Quisque id risus pharetra, pulvinar ipsum ut, sodales sapien. Curabitur euismod odio quis lectus hendrerit fringilla. Sed lorem libero, euismod quis accumsan ac, aliquam in ligula. Integer imperdiet
    enim non sapien luctus, a iaculis lorem tempus. Morbi ut pulvinar quam. Vivamus sodales justo ac metus laoreet, a condimentum turpis ultricies. Fusce enim risus, volutpat nec tempus vel, efficitur eget eros. Integer ac augue ut arcu pulvinar rhoncus.
    Vivamus tellus dui, posuere eu gravida sed, tempor eget sem. Praesent efficitur diam eget neque rhoncus auctor. Praesent tincidunt mauris sit amet lectus cursus gravida. Cras condimentum vestibulum euismod. Donec sit amet tellus at enim volutpat egestas.
    Maecenas risus tellus, aliquam vel sodales at, sagittis id lacus. Fusce pellentesque erat nunc. Suspendisse id cursus mauris. Donec ac pellentesque nibh. Ut vulputate lacus nec justo maximus mollis a nec nisl. Aliquam lectus diam, interdum vitae tellus
    quis, lacinia varius elit. Nam vehicula feugiat condimentum. Pellentesque at magna aliquet, vehicula sapien non, tincidunt nisi. Fusce convallis, orci dignissim faucibus placerat, massa lacus bibendum orci, suscipit mattis enim nunc lacinia est. Cras
    ante sem, dictum at metus eu, sagittis cursus mi. Integer in purus convallis, consectetur eros et, pulvinar risus. Fusce molestie nibh et purus pulvinar, non volutpat quam efficitur. Nulla facilisis metus non ornare elementum. Donec mollis tempor
    neque, sit amet varius nibh egestas sed. Integer vel dolor fermentum, dignissim urna ac, condimentum lacus. Proin imperdiet venenatis orci, et placerat magna dignissim in. Aliquam lobortis scelerisque maximus. Pellentesque sit amet libero in leo volutpat
    dignissim at vitae ligula. Nullam et sem nunc. Pellentesque at magna aliquet, vehicula sapien non, tincidunt nisi. Fusce convallis, orci dignissim faucibus placerat, massa lacus bibendum orci, suscipit mattis enim nunc lacinia est. Cras ante sem,
    dictum at metus eu, sagittis cursus mi. Integer in purus convallis, consectetur eros et, pulvinar risus. Fusce molestie nibh et purus pulvinar, non volutpat quam efficitur. Nulla facilisis metus non ornare elementum. Donec mollis tempor neque, sit
    amet varius nibh egestas sed. Integer vel dolor fermentum, dignissim urna ac, condimentum lacus. Proin imperdiet venenatis orci, et placerat magna dignissim in. Aliquam lobortis scelerisque maximus. Pellentesque sit amet libero in leo volutpat dignissim
    at vitae ligula. Nullam et sem nunc.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tincidunt id tellus ut scelerisque. Nullam dapibus id orci ac congue. Nunc mattis dictum dui id euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum
    primis in faucibus. Aliquam lorem turpis, venenatis nec rutrum et, blandit ac risus. Integer non sem quam. Mauris dictum, nisl id sollicitudin eleifend, purus ligula hendrerit mi, vitae ornare neque arcu pellentesque quam. Suspendisse consequat interdum
    dolor, maximus elementum metus lobortis vitae. Phasellus interdum erat vitae imperdiet pharetra. Sed vestibulum tellus arcu, vel hendrerit nisl elementum ut. Quisque non finibus dolor, non convallis libero. Pellentesque feugiat metus nisl, vel laoreet
    ligula posuere eu. In in tincidunt mi. In pharetra fermentum risus, non elementum erat blandit vel. Sed at turpis sed turpis finibus auctor. Morbi condimentum congue eros, nec sodales ligula fringilla vel. Suspendisse a nibh at massa convallis suscipit.
    Vestibulum accumsan lacus a facilisis molestie. Ut efficitur sodales ipsum eget pulvinar. Suspendisse faucibus rhoncus odio, convallis lacinia metus fringilla ac. Donec tincidunt tellus quis diam pharetra pellentesque. Praesent a mollis diam, eu vestibulum
    libero. Quisque euismod bibendum nibh in tempor. Curabitur congue ut tellus a malesuada. Proin id vestibulum velit. Pellentesque quis elit quis nulla lobortis bibendum in vitae odio. Maecenas eu rhoncus lectus. Quisque aliquet metus id facilisis egestas.
    Nunc posuere, felis in commodo viverra, eros ipsum pulvinar neque, sit amet accumsan massa tellus varius magna. Quisque id risus pharetra, pulvinar ipsum ut, sodales sapien. Curabitur euismod odio quis lectus hendrerit fringilla. Sed lorem libero,
    euismod quis accumsan ac, aliquam in ligula. Integer imperdiet enim non sapien luctus, a iaculis lorem tempus. Morbi ut pulvinar quam. Vivamus sodales justo ac metus laoreet, a condimentum turpis ultricies. Fusce enim risus, volutpat nec tempus vel,
    efficitur eget eros. Integer ac augue ut arcu pulvinar rhoncus. Vivamus tellus dui, posuere eu gravida sed, tempor eget sem. Praesent efficitur diam eget neque rhoncus auctor. Praesent tincidunt mauris sit amet lectus cursus gravida. Cras condimentum
    vestibulum euismod. Donec sit amet tellus at enim volutpat egestas. Maecenas risus tellus, aliquam vel sodales at, sagittis id lacus. Fusce pellentesque erat nunc. Suspendisse id cursus mauris. Donec ac pellentesque nibh. Ut vulputate lacus nec justo
    maximus mollis a nec nisl. Aliquam lectus diam, interdum vitae tellus quis, lacinia varius elit. Nam vehicula feugiat condimentum. Pellentesque at magna aliquet, vehicula sapien non, tincidunt nisi. Fusce convallis, orci dignissim faucibus placerat,
    massa lacus bibendum orci, suscipit mattis enim nunc lacinia est. Cras ante sem, dictum at metus eu, sagittis cursus mi. Integer in purus convallis, consectetur eros et, pulvinar risus. Fusce molestie nibh et purus pulvinar, non volutpat quam efficitur.
    Nulla facilisis metus non ornare elementum. Donec mollis tempor neque, sit amet varius nibh egestas sed. Integer vel dolor fermentum, dignissim urna ac, condimentum lacus. Proin imperdiet venenatis orci, et placerat magna dignissim in. Aliquam lobortis
    scelerisque maximus. Pellentesque sit amet libero in leo volutpat dignissim at vitae ligula. Nullam et sem nunc.
  </div>
  <div class="right-nav">
    right nav
  </div>
</div>
```

**Alternate Answer:**

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Comment: I want to scroll if the content overflows the main-wrapper (the one in the midde). How would I do it?

Comment: Close. I think the main content panel is supposed to only be to the bottom of the screen and then scroll. Otherwise, the content on your 3 nav bars scrolls off the screen

Comment: @PlotTwist set the main content div's height to `Calc(100vh - 200px)` (200px because that is the height of your top navbar). You also may need to factor in margins/borders as well.

Comment: @PlotTwist I added an alternate answer, does that help you? You can use this as a template and build your custom requirement!

Comment: YES! It's almost this. I've said that my page didn't have this gutters but I will study your solution to find out how to take them off. Thank you! I've accepted the answer.

Comment: Well, good luck changing anything there in 2 years or even now. It's going to be a nightmare. Magic numbers everywhere. I would suggest using CSS Grids for an easier, cleaner, more flexible and maintainable solution. Unless you need to support some really old, weird and smelly web browsers, then stay with floats. :) See my answer for CSS Grids.

Comment: @kamyl There is also bootstrap which might be the best option, that is why I mentioned it in my answer!

Comment: @Naren Murali yes, but "Bootstrap grids" is completely different concept that was created before "real" and native CSS Grid "came out" and was ready to use. There's no need to use "Bootstrap grid" anymore in new projects, unless you really need to have exact same look in ancient web browsers. We finally have the first proper tool for creating layouts and it's the CSS Grid (not to be confused with "bootstrap grid"). :)

Comment: @kamyl Oh is it, I know bootstrap and we can achieve this with just some custom css, let me check CSS grids out :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a marginally responsive solution: 
**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='page'>
      <div id='top'>
      </div>
      <div id='left'>
      </div>
      <div id='middle'>
      </div>
      <div id='right'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}
#page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#top {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
#middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
#right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 25%;
  left: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

And here's what it would look like: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxmGea?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick sample. You could go for making the elements absolute. This is kind of responsive as well. Good luck!

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 15%;
  background: red;
}

.left {
  width: 15%;
  height: 85%;
  background: blue;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.right {
  width: 15%;
  height: 85%;
  background: green;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.middle {
  width: 70%;
  height: 85%;
  left: 15%;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="nav">Top nav</div>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="middle">Content</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be surprised how easy this can be done with [CSS Grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). In short, CSS Grid is like Flexbox, but it works in 2d, rather than in 1d and is perfect for creating 2d layouts, like yours, in a easy and clean way. You can read and learn about CSS Grids [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). It's totally worth it!

I recreated the layout you want using CSS Grids. The code is below:

HTML:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="nav">Left navigation</div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
  <div class="side">Right navigation</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header"
    "nav content side"
  ;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  overflow: auto;
}

.side {
  grid-area: side;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

That's all. You can see it in action [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXdNBz?editors=1100).

In this example I set 200px of height for the header and 300px of width for both left and right navigation. Whole layout takes 100% of view width and 100% of view height [(vh)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length). There is also 10px of gap between all layout blocks, but you can set it to 0 if you'd like. I also set scrolling bars for overflowed content, as showed on your picture. These scrolling bars shows only when needed, but if you'd like to always display them, then set `overflow-y: scroll`.

Good luck!